# javascript ES6 sorting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I use only `sort()` without arguments, it returns correctly in alphabetical order.  When I try to add in arguments like below, it just returns the word in the same order the string was entered in.  I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
  var a = str.split("")
  return a.sort((a,b) => a-b).join("");
```

Comment: `a - b` is `NaN` when `a` and `b` are non-numeric strings. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `return a.sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : -1).join("")`; should do it

Comment: @Xufox to return the list of alpha characters in the array in order, like if i do `var array = ['c','d','a']` then `array.sort()`, it returns `['a',''b','c']`...i was wondering why when adding the arguments, it doesn't achieve the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Try using `localeCompare`:

```
var a = str.split("")
return a.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
```

[Docs on localeCompare here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings a - b won't work. 
You can use the ternary logic operator here:
a < b ? -1 : 1

Place that expression in the function you pass to sort and that should do the trick.

Comment: thanks , that works...just trying to understand that though.  Can you explain what that is doing?

Comment: @user10108817 `a < b ? -1 : 1` simply returns `-1` iff `a < b` and `1` iff `a >= b`. The `sort` method expects a number to be returned: if negative, `a` goes before `b`, if positive `a` goes after `b`. But this conditional expression isn’t semantically perfect, since it’s missing the `0` case, when `a` and `b` are equal. That’s why you should really use `a.localeCompare(b)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var str = 'zyxw'
var a = str.split("")
console.log(a)
var res = a.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join("");
console.log(res)
```